# How to assign two values for each element in an array discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is in discord.js. So I have three items each with a unique price (more items in the future).. Sending the name of the item for example "Item 1" should reply the price. How do I use the price variable in my code? I was thinking associative array but I think there's no associate array in JS.

1. Item 1 = 100
2. Item 2 = 300
3. Item 3 = 500

I have this code:

```
const items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];
const price = [100, 300, 500];

for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
if (message.content === items[i]) {
message.reply(PostPrice);
}
}
```

Comment: using the index? price[i]?

Comment: oh i see. thanks. i thought i should use something like associative array, so doing it this way works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `Map`, a built-in object in javascript

```js
const items = new Map()
//create map
items.set("item 1",100)
items.set("item 2",300)
items.set("item 3",500)

//check if item exists
if(items.has(message.content.toLowerCase())){
  message.reply("price: "+items.get(message.content.toLowerCase()))
}else{
  message.reply("this item doesnt exist");
}
```

Comment: You could make this more user friendly by using `message.content.toLowerCase()` instead of `message.content` and make the items also lower case because some people don't use capitalization in discord

Answer (score 1):

I would use json instead of arrays in this case

```js
const items = {"item 1": { price: 100 }, "item 2": { price: 300 }, "item 3": { price: 500 }}

if(items[message.content.toLowerCase()) {
message.reply("price: "+items[message.content.toLowerCase()]["price"])
} else {
message.reply("item doesnt exist")
}
```